# getItemView not defined for type Activity

Tags: android, parse-platform, custom-adapter

I am using Parse for my back-end and was using the ParseQueryAdapter to populate a listview.According to their [Android Guide](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui),I was supposed to override their getItemView method to customize my row item.Here's the code

```
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);
    if (v == null) {
    v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_item, null);
  }


  TextView descriptionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
  descriptionView.setText(object.getString("description"));
  return v;
}
```

The error returned is:`The method getItemView is not defined for the type Activity`

Answer (score 1):

You should extend ParseQueryAdapter and there to override getItemView not in activity. getItemView is a method from ParseQueryAdapter not from Activity

Answer (score 0):

Create Adapter Class like this

```
public class ParseAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> 
{
 private Activity activity;
public ParseAdapter(Activity act,
        com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> queryFactory) {
    super(act, queryFactory);
    this.activity = act;
    // setPaginationEnabled(false);
    setObjectsPerPage(2);
    setAutoload(true);
}



@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cus_show_new, null, false);

--------------

-----------

-------------
vi.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    }

return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this Parse tutorial, https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter, you should subclass the ParseQueryAdapter.